# Javascript - alternative to if/then for every variable assignment in this function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

This code works, but I have to think there is a much more efficient way to write it. This function takes in the values input into a webpage's form and creates a model that is then passed to C# to be inserted to a database. I need to ensure that if a given form field is blank, it will pass `null`, as opposed to `[ ]`.

Which is what would happen if the `listToArray` function runs against the field?

Is there a more efficient way to write this than using the if/then for every variable assignment?

```
async function newProfile(form) {
        var profile = {};
        if ($('#name').val() === "") { profile.name = null; } else { profile.name = listToArray($('#name').val());}
        if ($('#placeOfBirth').val() === "") { profile.placeOfBirth = null; } else { profile.placeOfBirth = listToArray($('#placeOfBirth').val());}
        if ($('#position').val() === "") { profile.position = null; } else { profile.position = listToArray($('#position').val());}
        //then imagine 15 more variables that have to be written that way
        //..
        //do some other irrelevant stuff
        //..
        $('.form').find(':input').prop("disabled", false);
    }
```

Comment: Yes - array mapping, utilizing functions, etc. but this a question for CodeReview, not StackOverflow.

Comment: `profile.name = $('#name').val() === "" ? null : listToArray($('#name').val())`? You could also extract a function to avoid the repetition.

Comment: A [trivial] loop over the names should suffice here, given as all the behavior is the same. Remember that JS allows `some_object["string name"]` to access a properties. Things become slightly (although not very) more interesting if there is a deviation on mapping/transform.

Answer (score 2):

You could use directly the properties with a ternary for the value.

```
async function newProfile(form) {
    var profile = {
            name: $('#name').val() === "" ? null : listToArray($('#name').val()),
            placeOfBirth: $('#placeOfBirth').val() === "" ? null : listToArray($('#placeOfBirth').val()),
            position: $('#position').val() === "" ? null : listToArray($('#position').val())
            // more, if necessary
        };

    $('.form').find(':input').prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Or use an array of keys.

```
async function newProfile(form) {
    var profile = Object.fromEntries(['name', 'placeOfBirth', 'position']
            .map(v => [v, $(`#${v}`).val() === "" ? null : listToArray($(`#${v}`).val()]));

    $('.form').find(':input').prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Comment: There is still too much duplication: which this answer nicely exposes: `var profile = { name: getListFromField("name"), .. }`.

Comment: one liners are fine, but you're still repeating the (relatively costly) `$(`#${v}`).val()`

Answer (score 2):

Create a function to do the repeated logic

```
async function newProfile(form) {
  const assign = val => val === "" ? null : listToArray(val);
  var profile = {};
  profile.name = assign($('#name').val());
  profile.placeOfBirth = assign($('#placeOfBirth').val());
  profile.position = assign($('#position').val());
}
```

Or better yet combine this answer with nina's first answer (credit where credit is due I say)

```
async function newProfile(form) {
  const assign = val => val === "" ? null : listToArray(val);
  var profile = {
    name: assign($('#name').val()),
    placeOfBirth: assign($('#placeOfBirth').val()),
    position: assign($('#position').val())
  }
}
```

and if the `$` and `.val()` part is ALWAYS present

```
async function newProfile(form) {
  const assign = sel => {
      const val = $(sel).val();
      return val === "" ? null : listToArray(val);
  };
  var profile = {
    name: assign('#name'),
    placeOfBirth: assign('#placeOfBirth'),
    position: assign('#position')
  }
}
```

Comment: Syntax errors :-) That said, this is the sort of duplication-reduction I'd expect in any answer dealing with such commonalities.

Comment: orgot the closing `)` :p

Answer (score 2):

The below will work I hope. Not tested. You can have similar call to any future variables too.

```
async function newProfile(form) {
    var profile = {};
    //if ($('#name').val() === "") { profile.name = null; } else { profile.name = listToArray($('#name').val());}
    //if ($('#placeOfBirth').val() === "") { profile.placeOfBirth = null; } else { profile.placeOfBirth = listToArray($('#placeOfBirth').val());}
    //if ($('#position').val() === "") { profile.position = null; } else { profile.position = listToArray($('#position').val());}

    profile.name = evaluatedata($('#name').val());
    profile.placeOfBirth = evaluatedata($('#placeOfBirth').val());
    profile.position = evaluatedata($('#position').val());
    //then imagine 15 more variables that have to be written that way
    //..
    //do some other irrelevant stuff
    //..
    $('.form').find(':input').prop("disabled", false);
}

function evaluatedata(value){
    if(value === ""){
        return null;
    }else
    {
    return listToArray(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is non-necessary duplication here with `$('#position').val()` and `$(valueindex).val()`, but a good start. One alternative: `function evaluatedata(name){ var value = $(name).val(); .. }`.

Comment: yeah. I  missed it, will update the answer